# Chances of a shuffled deck being sorted only by color

Tags: probability, card-games

**QUESTION (TL;DR)**

Let's assume you are handed a deck of 52, standard cards which are already shuffled.  You take the the deck and mindlessly shuffle it for a few minutes.  After the shuffle, you turn over the deck to find that all of the cards are split into two piles-- red on top, black on bottom (or black on top, red on bottom.)  However, each color-pile is randomly sorted.

What are the chances of such an event occurring?

**BONUS POINTS**

Follow-up question, which doesn't have to be answered.  How would the probability change if the deck was pre-color sorted?

In other words, if one started with two randomly sorted color piles and then shuffled the deck a random number of times, how would the probability change that the deck were to return to a state *similar* to how is started?  Assume a traditional shuffle, splitting the deck into two piles and then *fuzzy* merging every 1 or 2 cards on each side, what would be the chances that the deck would resort itself into two color piles after an small but optimized number of shuffles?

**WHY I ASK**

This is important to me for my sanity.  After playing a game with some friends in late-high school, I remember taking the deck of cards we were using (with no jokers) and mindlessly handling it.  There is chance that at one point I sorted the deck by color or suits.  I was mindlessly fiddling with the deck, so even though I never recall sorting it in any way, I know that if given a deck to hold, that is something I would very likely, mindlessly do.

After handling the deck for a while, I distinctly recall shuffling it at least a few times, turning it over and observing a color sorted deck.  My heart pounded as I thumbed through the cards because I couldn't believe what I was seeing.  It was... impossible.

To be fair, I've never felt that this was realistically possible.  I'm too rational to accept that I started with a well shuffled deck.  Before I shuffled the cards, I must have done *something* to the deck.  For the scope of this exercise, what I did doesn't matter. I've resolved that I must have done something that my short term memory had forgotten before shuffling the deck 3-10 times which must have been a factor in the outcome.

Regardless of what really happened, this has been a math problem that has stuck in my head for over 16 years!  What are the chances of this happening?

Comment: Is it _necessary_ for the black and red piles to be (separately) unsorted? If so, how would you define unsorted?

Comment: Imagine if you took one side of the deck (says the red) and you saw `{ KH, 2D, 5D, 7H, 2H, AH, 3D, ... }`  The same would be true for the black half `{ 4C, QC, JC, 6S, 6C, 2S, ...}`.  In other words, within each color pile, there is no defined order.  The cards of one color appear to be in a random order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is
$$
\frac{26!\cdot 26!\cdot 2}{52!}
$$
If we know that the red cards are all first, and the black cards are last, there are $26!$ ways for each of those piles to be shuffled. So there are $26! \cdot 26!$ ways of organizing a deck of cards with reds first, blacks last, and there are $52!$ total ways of organizing the deck. The last factor $2$ is there because blacks first, reds last is also a solution with the same probability.

If you want to specify that the reds and blacks are not to be ordered, you have to swap $26!$ with $(26! - n)$ where $n$ is the number of combinations you'd consider "sorted".

Comment: Ha! It is just as I had suspected. I *must* be crazy.  This is practically impossible. ;)